# Gradle grails - how to exclude dependency based on environment?

Tags: grails, gradle, dependency-management, environment

I have a project where I want to include the console plugin for certain environments but not for others - it should go in the (custom) deployTest environment, but not for Production.

If I build the app using grails, I have a BuildConfig.groovy that looks like:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

/// some stuff

plugins {
    /// more dependencies       

        if (Environment.current != Environment.PRODUCTION){
            compile ":console:1.5.1"
        }


    }
}
```

Dependency resolution for Grails when using Gradle to build it is based on the build.gradle file, not the BuildConfig.groovy.

How do I achieve this please?

Answer (score 4):

It seems more to me like you want to INCLUDE a dependency based upon the environment.  However, the approach will be the same either way.  In your build.gradle file you have a 'dependencies' section.  Since this is Groovy, it is code.  The -PgrailsEnv value is used by gradle to specify the environment.  Just use that:

```
dependencies {
    // if no property, then gradle will be default to prod.  So test
    //   for that or having it explicitly provided
    if (!project.hasProperty('grailsEnv') || project.grailsEnv.equals('prod')) {
         compile ':console:1.5.1'
    }
}
```